# Perl Anonymous Subroutine/Function error

Tags: perl, nested, anonymous-function, anonymous, subroutine

I have the following piece of code: (extremely simplified for the purposes of this question, but perfectly illustrates the problem I am having)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

&outer;
my $connected_sub;

sub outer {
    print "HELLO\n";

    &$connected_sub;
    $connected_sub = sub {
        print "GOODBYE\n";
    }
}
```

When run the program gives this output and error:

```
HELLO
Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry at subTesting line 13.
Can't use string ("") as a subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use at subTesting.pl line 13.
```

Am I totally overlooking something here? I cannot understand or work out what the problem with this is.

Comment: `&outer;` has a very special meaning (evne more special than `&outer()`). Don't do that. Use `outer()`.

Comment: Kindly limit your use of bold to things of unusual importance.  No one likes being yelled at all the time.

Comment: @darch - Okay then, I find it easier to read and understand when things are clearly separated/or titled, which is why I do it, but I appreciate others might not so I'll bear that in mind, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $connected_sub is not initializated. Try to assign to an anonymous sub:

```
my $connected_sub = sub {
   print "The code you need to run\n";
}
```

At the definition, and drop the code after the &$connected_sub call

This is the complete example modified:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my $connected_sub = sub {
   print "GOODBYE\n";
};

&outer;

sub outer
{
        print "HELLO\n";
        &$connected_sub;
 }
```

Answer (score 10):

To clarify:

*Subroutine definitions* happen in the compilation stage.  Thus code like this will work:

```
foo();

sub foo { print "No need to declare me before calling!"; }
```

But an *assignment* doesn't actually happen until that line of code is called.  That is why this won't work:

```
my $foo;

&$foo();

$foo = sub { print "Foo hasn't been set to me when you try to call me." }
```

Answer (score 5):

I assume that what you are trying to do here is assign an anonymous sub to the variable `$connected_sub`. This is not a good way to do it.

What you are doing is taking an empty variable, trying to use it as a code reference, assigning a code reference to it, then exiting the sub and *then* declaring the variable with `my`. Not the best order of doing things.

What you probably want to do is return a value which can be assigned to the variable, like so:

```
my $connected = outer();
$connected->();

sub outer {
    print "HELLO\n";
    my $sub = sub { print "GOODBYE\n"; }
    return $sub;
}
```

Using a lexical variable inside a subroutine is somewhat confusing, I think. Besides the general drawbacks of using global variables, the subroutine is also compiled before the code is executed and the variable declared.

Also, when calling a subroutine, the standard way of doing so is

```
name(@args);
```

Where `@args` is your argument list. Using `&` is old style perl, and using it has a special meaning (override prototypes). When using an anonymous sub in a variable, use the `->()` notation.

Comment: thanks for the point about using `->()` with anonymous sub routines, will remember that in the future

Comment: Actually, declarations happen at compile time.  *Initializations* happen at run time.  Yes, that means that `my $x = 5;` has both a compile-time and a run-time effect.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using `$connected_stub` before it is initialized.  Try to move the initialization up, like:

```
    $connected_sub = sub {
    print "GOODBYE\n";

    }
    &$connected_sub;
```